# How I can make my Discord bot to read who moved an user from voice channel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

How I can make my Discord bot to read when a user was moved from voice channel by someone and to see who moved that user?  I am not even sure if this is possible.

Comment: You can use the `fetchAuditLogs()` method of `Guild` with the `options.type` set to `MEMBER_MOVE` in the `voiceStateUpdate` event of client. Based on the response, you can determine if the user moved to another channel, was moved, or was disconnected.

Comment: And i can see who moved that user ?

Comment: Yes. If you take a look at the documentation, [GuildAuditLogsEntry](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildAuditLogsEntry) has a property called `executor`, which is the moderator that moved the user. `GuildAuditLogsEntry.target` is the user that was moved.

Comment: Thank you! I will read all about this what you told me.

Comment: Hi i got the data i need but still have a problem   GuildAuditLogsEntry.target   gives me NULL... and idk why.

Comment: @Jakye Hi i got the data i need but still have a problem GuildAuditLogsEntry.target gives me NULL... and idk why. Can you help me pls?

Comment: That was my bad. `MEMBER_MOVE` doesn't provide any target. Only the executor.